# Can't access the array that I input

Tags: java, arrays

The array that I input is not proceeding to report.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class PSS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        login();

    }

    public static void login() {

        String user;
        String pass;
        System.out.println("--- LogIn ---\n");
        Scanner get = new Scanner(System. in );
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter Username: ");
            user = get.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter Password: ");
            pass = get.nextLine();
            if (!user.equals("admin") || !pass.equals("pass")) System.out.print("\nInvalid Input\n\n");

        } while (!user.equals("admin") || !pass.equals("pass"));
        MMenu();

    }
    public static void MMenu() {
        Scanner is = new Scanner(System. in );

        int[] code = new int[10];
        String[] Pname = new String[10];
        String[] descrip = new String[10];
        double[] Sellprice = new double[10];
        double[] BuyPrice = new double[10];
        int[] quanti1 = new int[10];

        System.out.print("\n--- Main Menu ---\n");

        System.out.println("\n1 - File Maintenance.");
        System.out.println("2 - Transaction.");
        System.out.println("3 - Report.");
        System.out.println("4 - Log-out.");

        System.out.println("Enter Choice: ");

        int a = is.nextInt();

        if (a == 1) {
            System.out.println("--- File Maintenance ---\n");
            Scanner are = new Scanner(System. in );

            System.out.println("\n(a) - Add Product.");
            System.out.println("(e) - Edit Product.");
            System.out.println("(d) - Delete Product.");
            System.out.println("(b) - Back to Main Menu\n");

            System.out.print("Enter Choice: \n");

            char b = are.next().charAt(0);

            if (b == 'a') {
                int d = 0;
                int c = 0;
                System.out.println("*****************************");
                System.out.println("Add Product ");

                Scanner was = new Scanner(System. in );




                do {

                    System.out.println("*****************************");
                    System.out.print("Product No.: ");
                    code[c] = was.nextInt();
                    was.nextLine();

                    System.out.print("Product Name: ");
                    Pname[c] = was.nextLine();

                    System.out.print("Description: ");
                    descrip[c] = was.nextLine();

                    System.out.print("Buying Price: ");
                    BuyPrice[c] = was.nextDouble();

                    System.out.print("Selling Price: ");
                    Sellprice[c] = was.nextDouble();

                    System.out.println("\ndo you want to add more? (1 - Yes/0 - No)");
                    d = was.nextInt();

                    c++;

                } while (d != 0);
                MMenu();

            }


            if (b == 'e') {
                System.out.println("This page is Under Construction.\n");
                MMenu();
            }
            if (b == 'd') {
                System.out.println("This page is Under Construction.\n");
                MMenu();
            }
            if (b == 'b') {
                MMenu();
            }
        }
        if (a == 2) {
            System.out.println("*****************************");
            System.out.println("---Transaction---");
            Scanner were = new Scanner(System. in );
            int f;

            System.out.println("1 - Stock - in");
            System.out.println("2 - Sell Items\n");

            System.out.println("Enter Choice: ");

            f = were.nextInt();

            if (f == 1) {
                System.out.println("----Stock-in----");

                Scanner be = new Scanner(System. in );

                int q1 = 0;
                int q2;
                int h;

                do {
                    System.out.print("Enter Product No.: ");
                    int g = be.nextInt();

                    if (g == (code[0])) {


                        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[0]);
                        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[0]);
                        System.out.println("Buying Price: " + BuyPrice[0]);
                        System.out.println("Selling Price: " + Sellprice[0]);
                        System.out.println("Quantity in-hand: " + quanti1[0]);
                        System.out.print("Enter Quantity: ");
                        quanti1[0] = be.nextInt();
                        q2 = quanti1[0] + q1;
                        q1 = quanti1[0];
                        quanti1[0] = q2;

                    } else if (g == (code[1])) {

                        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[1]);
                        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[1]);
                        System.out.println("Buying Price: " + BuyPrice[1]);
                        System.out.println("Selling Price: " + Sellprice[1]);
                        System.out.println("Quantity in-hand: " + quanti1[1]);
                        System.out.print("Enter Quantity: ");
                        quanti1[1] = be.nextInt();
                        q2 = quanti1[1] + q1;
                        q1 = quanti1[1];
                        quanti1[1] = q2;

                    } else if (g == (code[2])) {

                        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[2]);
                        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[2]);
                        System.out.println("Buying Price: " + BuyPrice[2]);
                        System.out.println("Selling Price: " + Sellprice[2]);
                        System.out.println("Quantity in-hand: " + quanti1[2]);
                        System.out.print("Enter Quantity: ");
                        quanti1[2] = be.nextInt();
                        q2 = quanti1[2] + q1;
                        q1 = quanti1[2];
                        quanti1[2] = q2;

                    } else if (g == (code[3])) {

                        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[3]);
                        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[3]);
                        System.out.println("Buying Price: " + BuyPrice[3]);
                        System.out.println("Selling Price: " + Sellprice[3]);
                        System.out.println("Quantity in-hand: " + quanti1[3]);
                        System.out.print("Enter Quantity: ");
                        quanti1[3] = be.nextInt();
                        q2 = quanti1[3] + q1;
                        q1 = quanti1[3];
                        quanti1[3] = q2;

                    } else if (g == (code[4])) {

                        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[4]);
                        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[4]);
                        System.out.println("Buying Price: " + BuyPrice[4]);
                        System.out.println("Selling Price: " + Sellprice[4]);
                        System.out.println("Quantity in-hand: " + quanti1[4]);
                        System.out.print("Enter Quantity: ");
                        quanti1[4] = be.nextInt();
                        q2 = quanti1[4] + q1;
                        q1 = quanti1[4];
                        quanti1[4] = q2;

                    } else if (g == (code[5])) {

                        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[5]);
                        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[5]);
                        System.out.println("Buying Price: " + BuyPrice[5]);
                        System.out.println("Selling Price: " + Sellprice[5]);
                        System.out.println("Quantity in-hand: " + quanti1[5]);
                        System.out.print("Enter Quantity: ");
                        quanti1[5] = be.nextInt();
                        q2 = quanti1[5] + q1;
                        q1 = quanti1[5];
                        quanti1[5] = q2;

                    } else if (g == (code[6])) {

                        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[6]);
                        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[6]);
                        System.out.println("Buying Price: " + BuyPrice[6]);
                        System.out.println("Selling Price: " + Sellprice[6]);
                        System.out.println("Quantity in-hand: " + quanti1[6]);
                        System.out.print("Enter Quantity: ");
                        quanti1[6] = be.nextInt();
                        q2 = quanti1[6] + q1;
                        q1 = quanti1[6];
                        quanti1[6] = q2;

                    } else if (g == (code[7])) {

                        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[7]);
                        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[7]);
                        System.out.println("Buying Price: " + BuyPrice[7]);
                        System.out.println("Selling Price: " + Sellprice[7]);
                        System.out.println("Quantity in-hand: " + quanti1[7]);
                        System.out.print("Enter Quantity: ");
                        quanti1[7] = be.nextInt();
                        q2 = quanti1[7] + q1;
                        q1 = quanti1[7];
                        quanti1[7] = q2;

                    } else if (g == (code[8])) {

                        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[8]);
                        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[8]);
                        System.out.println("Buying Price: " + BuyPrice[8]);
                        System.out.println("Selling Price: " + Sellprice[8]);
                        System.out.println("Quantity in-hand: " + quanti1[8]);
                        System.out.print("Enter Quantity: ");
                        quanti1[8] = be.nextInt();
                        q2 = quanti1[8] + q1;
                        q1 = quanti1[8];
                        quanti1[8] = q2;

                    } else if (g == (code[9])) {

                        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[9]);
                        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[9]);
                        System.out.println("Buying Price: " + BuyPrice[9]);
                        System.out.println("Selling Price: " + Sellprice[9]);
                        System.out.println("Quantity in-hand: " + quanti1[9]);
                        System.out.print("Enter Quantity: ");
                        quanti1[9] = be.nextInt();
                        q2 = quanti1[9] + q1;
                        q1 = quanti1[9];
                        quanti1[9] = q2;

                    }
                    System.out.println("\ndo you want to stock in another items? (1 - Yes/0 - No)");
                    h = be.nextInt();

                } while (h == 1);
            }
            if (f == 2) {
                System.out.println("----Sell----");

                Scanner the = new Scanner(System. in );

                System.out.print("Enter Product No.: ");
                int co = the.nextInt();

                double total;
                double C;
                double P;



                if (co == (code[0])) {

                    System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[0]);
                    System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[0]);
                    System.out.println("Quantity in hand: " + quanti1[0]);
                    System.out.print("Quantity to buy: ");
                    int quanti2 = the.nextInt();
                    total = Sellprice[0] * quanti2;
                    System.out.println("Total: \n" + total);
                    System.out.print("Pay: ");
                    P = the.nextDouble();
                    C = P - total;
                    System.out.print("Change: " + C);
                    int quanti3 = quanti1[0] - quanti2;
                    quanti1[0] = quanti3;



                } else if (co == (code[1])) {

                    System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[1]);
                    System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[1]);
                    System.out.println("Quantity in hand: " + quanti1[1]);
                    System.out.print("Quantity to buy: ");
                    int quanti2 = the.nextInt();
                    total = Sellprice[1] * quanti2;
                    System.out.println("Total: " + total);
                    System.out.print("\nPay: ");
                    P = the.nextDouble();
                    C = P - total;
                    System.out.print("Change: " + C);
                    int quanti3 = quanti1[1] - quanti2;
                    quanti1[1] = quanti3;



                } else if (co == (code[2])) {

                    System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[2]);
                    System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[2]);
                    System.out.println("Quantity in hand: " + quanti1[2]);
                    System.out.print("Quantity to buy: ");
                    int quanti2 = the.nextInt();
                    total = Sellprice[2] * quanti2;
                    System.out.print("Total: " + total);
                    System.out.print("\nPay: ");
                    P = the.nextDouble();
                    C = P - total;
                    System.out.print("Change: " + C);
                    int quanti3 = quanti1[2] - quanti2;
                    quanti1[2] = quanti3;



                } else if (co == (code[3])) {

                    System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[3]);
                    System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[3]);
                    System.out.println("Quantity in hand: " + quanti1[3]);
                    System.out.print("Quantity to buy: ");
                    int quanti2 = the.nextInt();
                    total = Sellprice[3] * quanti2;
                    System.out.print("Total: " + total);
                    System.out.print("\nPay: ");
                    P = the.nextDouble();
                    C = P - total;
                    System.out.print("Change: " + C);
                    int quanti3 = quanti1[3] - quanti2;
                    quanti1[3] = quanti3;



                } else if (co == (code[4])) {

                    System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[4]);
                    System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[4]);
                    System.out.println("Quantity in hand: " + quanti1[4]);
                    System.out.print("Quantity to buy: ");
                    int quanti2 = the.nextInt();
                    total = Sellprice[4] * quanti2;
                    System.out.print("Total: " + total);
                    System.out.print("\nPay: ");
                    P = the.nextDouble();
                    C = P - total;
                    System.out.print("Change: " + C);
                    int quanti3 = quanti1[4] - quanti2;
                    quanti1[4] = quanti3;



                } else if (co == (code[5])) {

                    System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[5]);
                    System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[5]);
                    System.out.println("Quantity in hand: " + quanti1[5]);
                    System.out.print("Quantity to buy: ");
                    int quanti2 = the.nextInt();
                    total = Sellprice[5] * quanti2;
                    System.out.print("Total: " + total);
                    System.out.print("\nPay: ");
                    P = the.nextDouble();
                    C = P - total;
                    System.out.print("Change: " + C);
                    int quanti3 = quanti1[5] - quanti2;
                    quanti1[5] = quanti3;



                } else if (co == (code[6])) {

                    System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[6]);
                    System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[6]);
                    System.out.println("Quantity in hand: " + quanti1[6]);
                    System.out.print("Quantity to buy: ");
                    int quanti2 = the.nextInt();
                    total = Sellprice[1] * quanti2;
                    System.out.print("Total: \n" + total);
                    System.out.print("Pay: ");
                    P = the.nextDouble();
                    C = P - total;
                    System.out.print("Change: " + C);
                    int quanti3 = quanti1[6] - quanti2;
                    quanti1[6] = quanti3;



                } else if (co == (code[7])) {

                    System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[7]);
                    System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[7]);
                    System.out.println("Quantity in hand: " + quanti1[7]);
                    System.out.print("Quantity to buy: ");
                    int quanti2 = the.nextInt();
                    total = Sellprice[7] * quanti2;
                    System.out.print("Total: \n" + total);
                    System.out.print("Pay: ");
                    P = the.nextDouble();
                    C = P - total;
                    System.out.print("Change: " + C);
                    int quanti3 = quanti1[7] - quanti2;
                    quanti1[7] = quanti3;



                } else if (co == (code[8])) {

                    System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[8]);
                    System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[8]);
                    System.out.println("Quantity in hand: " + quanti1[8]);
                    System.out.print("Quantity to buy: ");
                    int quanti2 = the.nextInt();
                    total = Sellprice[8] * quanti2;
                    System.out.print("Total: \n" + total);
                    System.out.print("Pay: ");
                    P = the.nextDouble();
                    C = P - total;
                    System.out.print("Change: " + C);
                    int quanti3 = quanti1[8] - quanti2;
                    quanti1[8] = quanti3;



                } else if (co == (code[9])) {

                    System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[9]);
                    System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[9]);
                    System.out.println("Quantity in hand: " + quanti1[9]);
                    System.out.print("Quantity to buy: ");
                    int quanti2 = the.nextInt();
                    total = Sellprice[9] * quanti2;
                    System.out.print("Total: " + total);
                    System.out.print("\nPay: ");
                    P = the.nextDouble();
                    C = P - total;
                    System.out.print("Change: " + C);
                    int quanti3 = quanti1[9] - quanti2;
                    quanti1[9] = quanti3;



                }

            }
            MMenu();
        }
        if (a == 3) {
            System.out.print("---Report---\n\n");



            System.out.println("Products Available\n");
            System.out.println("| Product No.      | Name         | Price      | Quantity     |");
            System.out.println("|" + code[0] + "   " + Pname[0] + "    " + Sellprice[0] + "     " + quanti1[0] + "   ");
            System.out.println("|" + code[1] + "   " + Pname[1] + "    " + Sellprice[1] + "     " + quanti1[1] + "   ");
            System.out.println("|" + code[2] + "   " + Pname[2] + "    " + Sellprice[2] + "     " + quanti1[2] + "   ");
            System.out.println("|" + code[3] + "   " + Pname[3] + "    " + Sellprice[3] + "     " + quanti1[3] + "   ");
            System.out.println("|" + code[4] + "   " + Pname[4] + "    " + Sellprice[4] + "     " + quanti1[4] + "   ");
            System.out.println("|" + code[5] + "   " + Pname[5] + "    " + Sellprice[5] + "     " + quanti1[5] + "   ");
            System.out.println("|" + code[6] + "   " + Pname[6] + "    " + Sellprice[6] + "     " + quanti1[6] + "   ");
            System.out.println("|" + code[7] + "   " + Pname[7] + "    " + Sellprice[7] + "     " + quanti1[7] + "   ");
            System.out.println("|" + code[8] + "   " + Pname[8] + "    " + Sellprice[8] + "     " + quanti1[8] + "   ");
            System.out.println("|" + code[9] + "   " + Pname[9] + "    " + Sellprice[9] + "     " + quanti1[9] + "   ");

            MMenu();
        }

        if (a == 4) {
            System.out.println("Logging out... \nHave a nice day!");
            login();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Pl send full code... What are the issue you are facing

Comment: how to post a full code? sorry this is my first time.

Comment: The same way that you posted the code that you already posted!

Comment: use `List` instead of arrays

Comment: you are doing it very complex way and products will increase so you can't fix it. so use `List<Product>` list with product object

Comment: I don't know how to use that one.

Comment: can you give me some hints on what i will change? please i need help 2 days to go.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;

class PSS
{

```
public static void main (String [] args)
    {

    login();

    }

public static void login()
    {

    String user; String pass;
    System.out.println ("\n--- LogIn ---\n");
    Scanner get = new Scanner (System.in);
    do{
        System.out.print ("Enter Username: ");
        user = get.nextLine();
        System.out.print ("Enter Password: ");
        pass = get.nextLine();
     if (!user.equals ("admin") || !pass.equals("pass"))
        System.out.print ("\nInvalid Input\n\n");

}   while (!user.equals("admin") || !pass.equals("pass"));
        MMenu();

    }
public static void MMenu(){
    int m = 0;

do{
        Scanner is = new Scanner (System.in);

            int [] code = new int [10];
            String [] Pname = new String [10];
            String [] descrip = new String [10];
            double [] Sellprice = new double [10];
            double [] BuyPrice = new double [10];
            int [] quanti1 = new int [10];

    System.out.print ("\n--- Main Menu ---\n");

    System.out.println ("\n1 - File Maintenance.");
    System.out.println ("2 - Transaction.");
    System.out.println ("3 - Report.");
    System.out.println ("4 - Log-out.");

    System.out.println ("Enter Choice: ");

    int a = is.nextInt();

    if (a == 1)
        {
        System.out.println ("--- File Maintenance ---\n");
        Scanner are = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println ("\n(a) - Add Product.");
        System.out.println ("(e) - Edit Product.");
        System.out.println ("(d) - Delete Product.");
        System.out.println ("(b) - Back to Main Menu\n");

        System.out.print ("Enter Choice: \n");

        char b = are.next().charAt(0);

            if (b=='a')
                {
                    int d = 0;
                    int c = 0;
                System.out.println("*****************************");
                System.out.println("Add Product ");

                Scanner was = new Scanner (System.in);




                do {

                System.out.println("*****************************");
                System.out.print("Product No.: ");
                code[c] = was.nextInt();
                was.nextLine();

                System.out.print("Product Name: ");
                Pname[c] = was.nextLine();

                System.out.print("Description: ");
                descrip[c] = was.nextLine();

                System.out.print("Buying Price: ");
                BuyPrice[c] = was.nextDouble();

                System.out.print("Selling Price: ");
                Sellprice[c] = was.nextDouble();

                System.out.println("\ndo you want to add more? (1 - Yes/0 - No)");
                d = was.nextInt();

                c++;

                } while (d != 0);


            }


            if (b=='e')
                {
                System.out.println ("\nThis page is Under Construction.\n");

                }
            if (b=='d')
                {
                System.out.println ("\nThis page is Under Construction.\n");

                }
            if (b=='b')
                {
                System.out.println ("\nGoing back to main menu.\n");
                }

                System.out.println("\ndo you want to to go back to main menu? (1 - Yes/0 - No)");
                m = is.nextInt();
        }

     if (a == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("*****************************");
            System.out.println ("---Transaction---");
            Scanner were = new Scanner(System.in);
            int f;

        System.out.println ("1 - Stock - in");
        System.out.println ("2 - Sell Items\n");

        System.out.println ("Enter Choice: ");

        f = were.nextInt();

        if (f==1)
            {
        System.out.println("----Stock-in----");

        Scanner be = new Scanner (System.in);

        int q1 = 0;
        int q2;
        int h;

        do
        {
            System.out.print ("Enter Product No.: ");
            int g = be.nextInt();

                    if (g==(code[0]))
                    {


        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[0]);
        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[0]);
        System.out.println("Buying Price: " + BuyPrice[0]);
        System.out.println("Selling Price: " + Sellprice[0]);
        System.out.println ("Quantity in-hand: " + quanti1[0]);
        System.out.print ("Enter Quantity: ");
        quanti1[0] = be.nextInt();
        q2 = quanti1[0] + q1;
        q1  = quanti1[0];
        quanti1[0] = q2;

                    }

                else if (g==(code[1]))
                    {

        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[1]);
        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[1]);
        System.out.println("Buying Price: " + BuyPrice[1]);
        System.out.println("Selling Price: " + Sellprice[1]);
        System.out.println ("Quantity in-hand: " + quanti1[1]);
        System.out.print ("Enter Quantity: ");
        quanti1[1] = be.nextInt();
        q2 = quanti1[1] + q1;
        q1  = quanti1[1];
        quanti1[1] = q2;

                    }

            else if (g==(code[2]))
                    {

        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[2]);
        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[2]);
        System.out.println("Buying Price: " + BuyPrice[2]);
        System.out.println("Selling Price: " + Sellprice[2]);
        System.out.println ("Quantity in-hand: " + quanti1[2]);
        System.out.print ("Enter Quantity: ");
        quanti1[2] = be.nextInt();
        q2 = quanti1[2] + q1;
        q1  = quanti1[2];
        quanti1[2] = q2;

                    }

            else if (g==(code[3]))
                    {

        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[3]);
        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[3]);
        System.out.println("Buying Price: " + BuyPrice[3]);
        System.out.println("Selling Price: " + Sellprice[3]);
        System.out.println ("Quantity in-hand: " + quanti1[3]);
        System.out.print ("Enter Quantity: ");
        quanti1[3] = be.nextInt();
        q2 = quanti1[3] + q1;
        q1  = quanti1[3];
        quanti1[3] = q2;

                    }

                else if (g==(code[4]))
                    {

        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[4]);
        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[4]);
        System.out.println("Buying Price: " + BuyPrice[4]);
        System.out.println("Selling Price: " + Sellprice[4]);
        System.out.println ("Quantity in-hand: " + quanti1[4]);
        System.out.print ("Enter Quantity: ");
        quanti1[4] = be.nextInt();
        q2 = quanti1[4] + q1;
        q1  = quanti1[4];
        quanti1[4] = q2;

                    }
                else if (g==(code[5]))
                    {

        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[5]);
        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[5]);
        System.out.println("Buying Price: " + BuyPrice[5]);
        System.out.println("Selling Price: " + Sellprice[5]);
        System.out.println ("Quantity in-hand: " + quanti1[5]);
        System.out.print ("Enter Quantity: ");
        quanti1[5] = be.nextInt();
        q2 = quanti1[5] + q1;
        q1  = quanti1[5];
        quanti1[5] = q2;

                    }
            else if (g==(code[6]))
                    {

        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[6]);
        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[6]);
        System.out.println("Buying Price: " + BuyPrice[6]);
        System.out.println("Selling Price: " + Sellprice[6]);
        System.out.println ("Quantity in-hand: " + quanti1[6]);
        System.out.print ("Enter Quantity: ");
        quanti1[6] = be.nextInt();
        q2 = quanti1[6] + q1;
        q1  = quanti1[6];
        quanti1[6] = q2;

                    }

            else if (g==(code[7]))
                    {

        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[7]);
        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[7]);
        System.out.println("Buying Price: " + BuyPrice[7]);
        System.out.println("Selling Price: " + Sellprice[7]);
        System.out.println ("Quantity in-hand: " + quanti1[7]);
        System.out.print ("Enter Quantity: ");
        quanti1[7] = be.nextInt();
        q2 = quanti1[7] + q1;
        q1  = quanti1[7];
        quanti1[7] = q2;

                    }

            else if (g==(code[8]))
                    {

        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[8]);
        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[8]);
        System.out.println("Buying Price: " + BuyPrice[8]);
        System.out.println("Selling Price: " + Sellprice[8]);
        System.out.println ("Quantity in-hand: " + quanti1[8]);
        System.out.print ("Enter Quantity: ");
        quanti1[8] = be.nextInt();
        q2 = quanti1[8] + q1;
        q1  = quanti1[8];
        quanti1[8] = q2;

                    }

            else if (g==(code[9]))
                    {

        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[9]);
        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[9]);
        System.out.println("Buying Price: " + BuyPrice[9]);
        System.out.println("Selling Price: " + Sellprice[9]);
        System.out.println ("Quantity in-hand: " + quanti1[9]);
        System.out.print ("Enter Quantity: ");
        quanti1[9] = be.nextInt();
        q2 = quanti1[9] + q1;
        q1  = quanti1[9];
        quanti1[9] = q2;

                    }
        System.out.println("\ndo you want to stock in another items? (1 - Yes/0 - No)");
        h = be.nextInt();

        }while(h==1);

            }

    if (f==2)
        {
            System.out.println("----Sell----");

        Scanner the = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print ("Enter Product No.: ");
        int co = the.nextInt();

        double total = 0;
        double C;
        double P;
        int p;
        double total1 = 0;
        double total2;

    do
        {

                if (co==(code[0])){

        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[0]);
        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[0]);
        System.out.println("Quantity in hand: " + quanti1[0]);
        System.out.print("Quantity to buy: ");
        int quanti2  = the.nextInt();
        total = Sellprice[0]*quanti2;
        System.out.println("Total: \n" + total);
        int quanti3 = quanti1[0] - quanti2;
        quanti1[0] = quanti3;



            }

            else if (co==(code[1])){

        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[1]);
        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[1]);
        System.out.println("Quantity in hand: " + quanti1[1]);
        System.out.print("Quantity to buy: ");
        int quanti2  = the.nextInt();
        total = Sellprice[1]*quanti2;
        System.out.println("Total: " + total);
        System.out.print("\nPay: ");
        int quanti3 = quanti1[1] - quanti2;
        quanti1[1] = quanti3;



            }

            else if (co==(code[2])){

        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[2]);
        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[2]);
        System.out.println("Quantity in hand: " + quanti1[2]);
        System.out.print("Quantity to buy: ");
        int quanti2  = the.nextInt();
        total = Sellprice[2]*quanti2;
        System.out.print("Total: " + total);
        System.out.print("\nPay: ");
        int quanti3 = quanti1[2] - quanti2;
        quanti1[2] = quanti3;



            }

            else if (co==(code[3])){

        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[3]);
        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[3]);
        System.out.println("Quantity in hand: " + quanti1[3]);
        System.out.print("Quantity to buy: ");
        int quanti2  = the.nextInt();
        total = Sellprice[3]*quanti2;
        System.out.print("Total: " + total);
        int quanti3 = quanti1[3] - quanti2;
        quanti1[3] = quanti3;



            }

            else if (co==(code[4])){

        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[4]);
        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[4]);
        System.out.println("Quantity in hand: " + quanti1[4]);
        System.out.print("Quantity to buy: ");
        int quanti2  = the.nextInt();
        total = Sellprice[4]*quanti2;
        System.out.print("Total: " + total);
        int quanti3 = quanti1[4] - quanti2;
        quanti1[4] = quanti3;



            }

            else if (co==(code[5])){

        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[5]);
        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[5]);
        System.out.println("Quantity in hand: " + quanti1[5]);
        System.out.print("Quantity to buy: ");
        int quanti2  = the.nextInt();
        total = Sellprice[5]*quanti2;
        System.out.print("Total: " + total);
        int quanti3 = quanti1[5] - quanti2;
        quanti1[5] = quanti3;



            }

            else if (co==(code[6])){

        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[6]);
        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[6]);
        System.out.println("Quantity in hand: " + quanti1[6]);
        System.out.print("Quantity to buy: ");
        int quanti2  = the.nextInt();
        total = Sellprice[1]*quanti2;
        System.out.print("Total: \n" + total);
        int quanti3 = quanti1[6] - quanti2;
        quanti1[6] = quanti3;



            }

            else if (co==(code[7])){

        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[7]);
        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[7]);
        System.out.println("Quantity in hand: " + quanti1[7]);
        System.out.print("Quantity to buy: ");
        int quanti2  = the.nextInt();
        total = Sellprice[7]*quanti2;
        System.out.print("Total: \n" + total);
        int quanti3 = quanti1[7] - quanti2;
        quanti1[7] = quanti3;



            }

            else if (co==(code[8])){

        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[8]);
        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[8]);
        System.out.println("Quantity in hand: " + quanti1[8]);
        System.out.print("Quantity to buy: ");
        int quanti2  = the.nextInt();
        total = Sellprice[8]*quanti2;
        System.out.print("Total: \n" + total);
        int quanti3 = quanti1[8] - quanti2;
        quanti1[8] = quanti3;



            }

            else if (co==(code[9])){

        System.out.println("Product Name: " + Pname[9]);
        System.out.println("Description: " + descrip[9]);
        System.out.println("Quantity in hand: " + quanti1[9]);
        System.out.print("Quantity to buy: ");
        int quanti2  = the.nextInt();
        total = Sellprice[9]*quanti2;
        System.out.print("Total: " + total);
        int quanti3 = quanti1[9] - quanti2;
        quanti1[9] = quanti3;

            }
        total2 = total + total1;
        total1 = total;
        total =  total2;


        System.out.println("\ndo you want to stock in another items? (1 - Yes/0 - No)");
        p = the.nextInt();

        }while (p==1);

        System.out.println("\nPay: ");
        P = the.nextDouble();
        C = P - total;
        System.out.println("Change: " + C);

        }
        System.out.println("\ndo you want to to go back to main menu? (1 - Yes/0 - No)");
        m = is.nextInt();
        }



if (a == 3)
    {
        System.out.print("---Report---\n\n");



        System.out.println ("Products Available\n");
        System.out.println ("| Product No.      | Name         | Price      | Quantity     |");
        for (int k=0; k<10; k++){
        System.out.println ("|" + code[k] +  "   " + Pname[k] + "    "  +  Sellprice[k] + "     "  +  quanti1[k] + "   ");
        }
        System.out.println("\ndo you want to to go back to main menu? (1 - Yes/0 - No)");
        m = is.nextInt();

    }

if (a == 4)
    {
        System.out.println ("Logging out... \nHave a nice day!");
        login();
        }
} while (m==1);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are calling MMenu(); recursively so that the menu can be printed out repeatedly. But the arrays that you are trying to print are local variables inside MMenu().

```
public static void MMenu() {

Scanner is = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] code = new int[10]; // these are local variables in 
    String[] Pname = new String[10];
    String[] descrip = new String[10];
    double[] Sellprice = new double[10];
    double[] BuyPrice = new double[10];
    int[] quanti1 = new int[10];

    ...
            do {

                System.out.println("*****************************");
                System.out.print("Product No.: ");
                code[c] = was.nextInt();
                was.nextLine();

                System.out.print("Product Name: ");
                Pname[c] = was.nextLine();

                System.out.print("Description: ");
                descrip[c] = was.nextLine();

                System.out.print("Buying Price: ");
                BuyPrice[c] = was.nextDouble();

                System.out.print("Selling Price: ");
                Sellprice[c] = was.nextDouble();

                System.out.println("\ndo you want to add more? (1 - Yes/0 - No)");
                d = was.nextInt();

                c++;

            } while (d != 0);
            MMenu(); // this is where recursion happens, there are a lot such examples in your code, get rid of them and use loops
       ...
        }
```

So when you are adding a product, you are inside on MMenu(), let's call it A. The product information are stored in the local arrays in A.

After you finish adding product, you called MMenu() again in A, let's call it B. At this time, if you try to printout the arrays, you are printing out the local array in B,  but not in A. That's why you print out empty arrays.

**To solves this, use a loop instead of recursion to reprint the menus.**

PS: as suggested in the comment, your code is messed up, use a class to wrap the product information, and also break MMenu into several small methods to make it more modular and easier to debug

Comment: ah so what I'm going to do? I'll re-create other system but this time its a loop?

Comment: @zMoles can you try to clean up your code first? For example, you can use a loop to print out the report instead of having one line of code for each product. And can you write a sub method for each menu function - read product, print report, etc. After that, I can show you how to get rid of the recursion by using a loop.

Comment: ahm can you give some examples for breaking my menu?